# How to Print the DataHandler Content for SOAP Request

Tags: soap, datahandler, xmlstreamwriter

I have the object of `"javax.activation.DataHandler.DataHandler"`
and i saw that it has been added to SOAP request using the below command

```
org.apache.axiom.util.stax.XMLStreamWriterUtils.writeDataHandler()
```

I want to get the content from DataHandler, the content which is actually will be the part of the SOAP request, as i know it will be in the form of string.

thanks in advance!